# How to get current Cell position of an Excel sheet using Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

Is there any way to calculate or is there any built-in API to get the current `Cell position` of an Excel sheet using Apache Poi??

Like **A10** or **F61** or **AG34** or **BK567** etc.

*Note*: I'm using **poi3.9.jar**. Thanks in advance. It would be preferable if there's a built-in api.

I need this cell position because, I want to use the below Formula to set value.

Formula is : `cell.setCellFormula("G16/F16*100");`

Comment: Do you have an Apache POI `Cell` object that you need to get the reference for?

Comment: Yes, I have the `Cell` object. Actually I need to calculate the formula and put it in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the [Apache POI Cell object to hand](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html), you can call [cell.getAddress()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getAddress--) to get a [CellAddress object](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellAddress.html).

From that, you can cell [formatAsString](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#formatAsString--) to get the cell's address eg `A1`

```
int colNum = 2; // eg
Cell cell = row.getCell(colNum);
CellAddress addr = cell.getAddress();
String asExcel = addr.formatAsString(); // eg C3
```